# CSS selector for a select tag in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have this piece of HTML

```
<select multiple="" name="colonia_id[]" id="colonia_id[]" onchange="" size="10"></select>
```

I need to change the select menu width. I can't just use the width attribute in the select tag because the HTML is generated automatically. So I just have to use a CSS selector. I have tried to select the menu with the following and both work on Google Chrome...

```
select[multiple]{
  width:320px;
}

select[name="colonia_id[]"]{
  background-color:yellow; 
}
```

But they don't work with internet explorer. I can't just use select because there are other select menus in the form that I don't want to change.

How can I change the styles in that select menu in internet explorer?

Comment: Please give the whole HTML tree up to that select. Is there nothing that makes it unique in that form?

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, but here's a site to add to your tools if you don't use it already: http://caniuse.com/.

Comment: You're not testing in IE6, are you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
#colonia_id\[\] {
    background-color:yellow; 
}
```

By escaping the brackets, CSS recognizes them.  Works in IE8 and 7 (emulated).  Fine in Chrome too.  Here's a fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/97xnb/

Credit must go to this site where I found the idea:  [PigsLipstick](http://www.pigslipstick.com/index.php?/archives/168-Reference-CSS-to-DIV-ID-with-Square-Brackets.html)

Comment: That’s the best way. The selector `select[multiple]` should work, too, on IE 8, but the page must not trigger Quirks Mode then.

Comment: This also works in IE6, assuming the OP is testing in IE6, because both attribute selectors should work in IE7+.